# Delphi: Legit Status of a compiled app?

Tags: delphi

Lately I've been reading articles about computer security. I can't help to wonder, is there a way to know whether an app is compiled using a pirated copy of delphi or not?

Comment: Pirated copy of D is no less secure than legit one. In the fact, link between piracy and security is as weak as between marijuana and heroin in the so called "gateway theory".

Comment: Not true. Cracks and keygen are often vehicles to infect a PC, and the site to distribute them as well. If one is using them, it is very little security-aware. And if one is using a pirated copy, he is not honest as well, and I will be careful to use software from such a guy.

Comment: 2ldsandon: this is a weak link. Because _any_ files from the outside of the trust perimeter can contain malicious code. Shareware distribution sites like download.com where people caught their copy of **Win32.Induc.a** perfectly proved it. Re: morals - security is exact science, do not link them.

Comment: Yes, any file, but some files and sources are riskier than others. People and companies using pirated software are more at risk than those using only legitimate one. "More at risk" does not mean, of course, that each software compiled with a pirated copy is infected and the legitimate one is not. But the risk exists, especially it means that those people/company is not honest and cares little about security. Yes, infected software can come from everywhere **because someone made something he should have not done**. Like using a crack or a keygen, or visiting the wrong site.

Comment: 2ldsandon: you are mixing up honesty and security again. I cannot allow myself into philosophical fields of _honesty assessment_ or _moral audits_, sorry. I certify what warez itself is a risk factor itself, but refuse to make positive conclusion in the original question context.

Comment: @ldsandon: Many people used pirated software to circumvent draconian copy protection schemes - genuine pirates are not affected by these schemes and often legitimate customers wish to enjoy the same benefits as those pirates, rather than having to pay for the software TWICE over (once in cash, and again in inconvenience).  That simple fact pretty much blows a hole your link between pirates and intent/exposure to risk, because honest/legit users are "pirates" too. :)

Comment: @user205376: I am not mixing security and honesty. I am just pointing out that some behaviours are riskier than others. From a security point of view, I would be very careful using software from a supplier I know it doesn't use good security practices. It is not a "moral" assertion, it is simply a risk assessment outcome.
@Deltics: I do not care why someone uses cracks or keygens. I care about the risk they introduce. They are attack vectors, and can undermine security. You may accept the risk because of your dislike of protection schemes, I don't.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. From an EXE or DLL you can get only Delphi version and SKU.

Answer (score 2):

as a question, you're asking this because you have a pirated copy of Delphi? I don't want to start a flame discussion, just asking what is the real purpose of your question? Everybody knows that a "clean" hacked copy of a software development tool create the same "result product" as a genuine one. Your question is like 'if I have a pirated version of a SO this will burn my computer?'.No, it doesn't but it's not moral and legal.

Once again, I don't intend to argue with somebody or making accusations, but I don't understand your question.

best regards,
Radu

Comment: I don't have illegal copy of the software, if you must know. I was just wondering, whether software companies like Borland put security measures as such in their products. that's all.

Comment: that should be a good idea. but you know, for every lock in this world exist also a key to unlock it. that's the way.

Comment: Or a picklock. Or, as it's the case of some Kryptonite bike locks, a ballpen.

Answer (score 0):

As a complete guess, I'm going to have to say no. Especially since it seems to me that there are ways to make any program thing that it's not a pirate copy.